# SSIS Derived Column converting decimals to .00

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, percentage

I'm using SSIS 2012 and trying to get the Derived Column step to calculate and output an accurate percentage.

As an example, I have the following equations that includes 2 digits after the decimal:

(20177 * 100) / 26032 = 77.50

(3703 * 100) / 26032 = 14.22

In the Derived Column, my expression (with @allRecords = 26032) is as follows:

(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)((Populated * 100) / @[User::allRecords])

[image]

But I can't figure out why SSIS is dropping the preceding digits and replacing them with 0's

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result `(20177 * 100) / 26032` is a `INT` , therefore `77`. Then `77` convert to decimal become `77.00`.

```
(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)((DT_NUMERIC,10,2)(Populated * 100) / @[User::allRecords])
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the 100.0   This way you can maintain precision.  After all an INT/INT will return an INT.

```
(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)((Populated * 100.0) / @[User::allRecords])
```